# how to iterate in python dict and insert in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

```
from copy import deepcopy

tree={'A':['B','C'],
        'B':['D','E'],
        'C':['F','G']}

treedict=deepcopy(tree)




i need help here .i have a tree which is a dict containing lists.i wonder how i can insert  a node in the top of the tree and at the bottoom here is what i tried

def InsertNodeInTreeBottom(newnode,nodeparent,treedict):
         for k in treedict.iteritems():
             if (k==nodeparent):
                node=nodeparent
                children=treedict[node]
                children.append[newnode
     return treedict
```

but there is no change in the tree even after i try to add.

for example i would like InsertNodeInTreeBottom('X','F',treedict) ,the tree
must look like

```
tree={'A':['B','C'],
      'B':['D','E'],
      'C':['F','G']
      'F':['x']}
```

Comment: python dictionaries are unordered. If you want an ordered dictionary, try collections.OrderedDict.

Comment: your question is a bit ambiguous and the code is badly formatted. also see if this question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-for-loops-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I supposed your objective is to insert an element within a list identified by one of the dictionary key.

```
from copy import deepcopy

tree={'A':['B','C'],
        'B':['D','E'],
        'C':['F','G']}

treedict=deepcopy(tree)

def InsertNodeInTreeBottom(newnode,nodeparent,treedict):
    for k, v in treedict.items():
        if (k==nodeparent):
            treedict[k].append(newnode)
    return treedict  

InsertNodeInTreeBottom('AA', 'B', treedict)
```

will produce:

```
 {'C': ['F', 'G'], 'B': ['D', 'E', 'AA'], 'A': ['B', 'C']}
```

Notes:

- in python 3 there is no more `iteritems` for `dict` type.
- you can't use `[]` for `append` as it is a function
- dictionaries are unordered, so you can't really call them a tree. If you want to create a proper tree, you'd better use nested `tuple`, or set a dictionary semantic like 'left' and 'right' keys or build a proper class for it.

Comment: an orderedDict has order

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def InsertNodeInTreeBottom(newnode,nodeparent,treedict):
    for k in treedict:
        if (k==nodeparent):
            node=nodeparent
            children=treedict[node]
            children.append(newnode)
    return treedict
```

- use children.append(newnode) for append new item in list
- iterat on dict its return key